# Working with particles plugin and background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using particles plugin for the background with the background image. And the background image should be blurred. But the problem is with the image the particles are also getting blurred.

My Code as follows:

```js
/* ---- particles.js config ---- */

particlesJS("particles-js", {
  "particles": {
    "number": {
      "value": 30,
      "density": {
        "enable": true,
        "value_area": 320
      }
    },
    "color": {
      "value": "#ffffff"
    },
    "shape": {
      "type": "circle",
      "stroke": {
        "width": 0,
        "color": "#000000"
      },
      "polygon": {
        "nb_sides": 5
      },
      "image": {
        "src": "img/github.svg",
        "width": 100,
        "height": 100
      }
    },
    "opacity": {
      "value": 0.5,
      "random": false,
      "anim": {
        "enable": false,
        "speed": 1,
        "opacity_min": 0.1,
        "sync": false
      }
    },
    "size": {
      "value": 2,
      "random": true,
      "anim": {
        "enable": false,
        "speed": 25,
        "size_min": 0.1,
        "sync": false
      }
    },
    "line_linked": {
      "enable": true,
      "distance": 150,
      "color": "#ffffff",
      "opacity": 0.4,
      "width": 1
    },
    "move": {
      "enable": true,
      "speed": 6,
      "direction": "none",
      "random": false,
      "straight": false,
      "out_mode": "out",
      "bounce": false,
      "attract": {
        "enable": false,
        "rotateX": 600,
        "rotateY": 1200
      }
    }
  },
  "interactivity": {
    "detect_on": "canvas",
    "events": {
      "onhover": {
        "enable": true,
        "mode": "grab"
      },
      "onclick": {
        "enable": true,
        "mode": "push"
      },
      "resize": true
    },
    "modes": {
      "grab": {
        "distance": 140,
        "line_linked": {
          "opacity": 1
        }
      },
      "bubble": {
        "distance": 400,
        "size": 40,
        "duration": 2,
        "opacity": 8,
        "speed": 3
      },
      "repulse": {
        "distance": 200,
        "duration": 0.4
      },
      "push": {
        "particles_nb": 4
      },
      "remove": {
        "particles_nb": 2
      }
    }
  },
  "retina_detect": true
});


/* ---- stats.js config ---- */
```

```css
canvas {
  display: block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

/* ---- particles.js container ---- */

#particles-js {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: url("https://blackshellmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Commercial-Buildings.jpg");
  backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-filter: blur(4px);
  -moz-filter: blur(4px);
  -o-filter: blur(4px);
  -ms-filter: blur(4px);
  filter: blur(4px);
}
```

```html
<div id="particles-js"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/particlesjs/2.1.0/particles.js" defer="defer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js"></script>
```

Please have a look at the result there you can find the exact problem which I am facing. Even the particles are getting blurred how I can solve this.

Comment: you can use blur background image so you don't need to add blur filter

Comment: @Ezzuddin Yes, i can use. But I don't want my client to use everytime blur image whenever he wants to update the banner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply move the image outside and use a pseudo element for example to create a separate layer:

```js
/* ---- particles.js config ---- */

particlesJS("particles-js", {
  "particles": {
    "number": {
      "value": 30,
      "density": {
        "enable": true,
        "value_area": 320
      }
    },
    "color": {
      "value": "#ffffff"
    },
    "shape": {
      "type": "circle",
      "stroke": {
        "width": 0,
        "color": "#000000"
      },
      "polygon": {
        "nb_sides": 5
      },
      "image": {
        "src": "img/github.svg",
        "width": 100,
        "height": 100
      }
    },
    "opacity": {
      "value": 0.5,
      "random": false,
      "anim": {
        "enable": false,
        "speed": 1,
        "opacity_min": 0.1,
        "sync": false
      }
    },
    "size": {
      "value": 2,
      "random": true,
      "anim": {
        "enable": false,
        "speed": 25,
        "size_min": 0.1,
        "sync": false
      }
    },
    "line_linked": {
      "enable": true,
      "distance": 150,
      "color": "#ffffff",
      "opacity": 0.4,
      "width": 1
    },
    "move": {
      "enable": true,
      "speed": 6,
      "direction": "none",
      "random": false,
      "straight": false,
      "out_mode": "out",
      "bounce": false,
      "attract": {
        "enable": false,
        "rotateX": 600,
        "rotateY": 1200
      }
    }
  },
  "interactivity": {
    "detect_on": "canvas",
    "events": {
      "onhover": {
        "enable": true,
        "mode": "grab"
      },
      "onclick": {
        "enable": true,
        "mode": "push"
      },
      "resize": true
    },
    "modes": {
      "grab": {
        "distance": 140,
        "line_linked": {
          "opacity": 1
        }
      },
      "bubble": {
        "distance": 400,
        "size": 40,
        "duration": 2,
        "opacity": 8,
        "speed": 3
      },
      "repulse": {
        "distance": 200,
        "duration": 0.4
      },
      "push": {
        "particles_nb": 4
      },
      "remove": {
        "particles_nb": 2
      }
    }
  },
  "retina_detect": true
});


/* ---- stats.js config ---- */
```

```css
canvas {
  display: block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}


/* ---- particles.js container ---- */

#particles-js {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#particles-js:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("https://blackshellmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Commercial-Buildings.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-filter: blur(4px);
  -moz-filter: blur(4px);
  -o-filter: blur(4px);
  -ms-filter: blur(4px);
  filter: blur(4px);
}
```

```html
<div id="particles-js"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/particlesjs/2.1.0/particles.js" defer="defer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js"></script>
```